# PySimpleGUI radio buttons adding a 0 to values

Tags: radio-button, pysimplegui

I have an Excel file that I read into a df, When trying to loop through the header list  (col_list), the radio buttons adds a zero to the Value, causing it to crash....

import PySimpleGUI as sg

for item in col_list:

```
    sg.theme("reddit")
    layout = [[sg.T("")], [sg.T("        "), sg.Button(item, size=(20, 4))], [sg.T("")],
              [sg.T("         "), sg.Radio('Latitude:',"RADIO1",  default=False, key="Lat")],
              [sg.T("         "), sg.Radio('Longitude', "RADIO1", default=False, key="Lon")],
              [sg.T("         "), sg.Radio('Name:',"RADIO1",  default=False, key="Name")],
              [sg.T("         "), sg.Radio('Description:',"RADIO1",  default=False, key="Desc")],
              [sg.Button('OK'), sg.Button('Skip'), sg.Button('Quit')]]

    window = sg.Window('Choose how column will be displayed', layout, size=(300, 300))

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        print("event: ",event," values: ",values)
        input("read")
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=="Skip":
            break
        elif event == 'Quit':
            print("Stopping Application !!!")
            quit()
        elif event == 'OK':
            if values["Name"] == True:
                temp = {count: item}
                d1.update(temp)
            elif values["Lat"] == True:
                temp = {count: item}
                d1.update(temp)
            elif values["Lon"] == True:
                temp = {count: item}
                d1.update(temp)
            elif values["Desc"] == True:
                temp = {count: item}
                d1.update(temp)
        print(d1)
        window.close()
        count = count + 1
```

Printing out the events and values results with  "event:  OK  values:  {'Lat': False, 'Lon': False, 'Name0': True, 'Desc': False}"

the "Name" button has a zero added to it ???  Causing app to crash.

Comment: It looks like you have duplicate key in your layout, but this issue cannot be found in the provided code.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that was it, I had variables earlier in the routine using the same name !!!